# Combining depth- and breadth-first traversals in a single cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

My graph is a tree structure with root and end nodes, and a line of nodes between them with  `[:NEXT]->` relationships from one to the next. Some nodes along that path also have `[:BRANCH]->` relationships to other root nodes, and through them to other lines of nodes.

What Cypher query will return an ordered list of the nodes on the path from beginning to end, with any `BRANCH` relationships being included with the records for the nodes that have them?

**EDIT:** It's not a technical diagram, but the basic structure looks like this:

[image]

with each node depicted as a black circle. In this case, I would would want every node depicted here.

Comment: can you post a sample diagram of your graph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
MATCH p=(root)-[:NEXT*0..]->(leaf)
OPTIONAL MATCH (leaf)-[:BRANCH]->(branched)
RETURN leaf, branched, length(p) as l
ORDER BY l ASC
```

see also this graph-gist: http://gist.neo4j.org/?9042990

Answer (score 1):

This query - a bit slow - should work (I guess):

```
START n=node(startID), child=node(*)
MATCH (n)-[rels*]-(child)
WHERE all(r in rels WHERE type(r) IN ["NEXT", "BRANCH"])
RETURN *
```

That is based on [Neo4j 2.0.x Cypher syntax](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/).
Technically this query will stop at the end of the tree started from `startID`: that is because the end in the diagram above belongs to a single path, but not the end of all the branches.
I would also recommend to limit the cardinality of the relationships - `[rels*1..n]` - to prevent the query to go away...

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to control the order in which the nodes are returned as per the depth first or breadth first algo unless you have a variable to save previous element or kind of recursive call which I dont think is not possible using only Cypher.

What you can do

```
MATCH p =(n)-[:NEXT*]->(end) 
WITH collect(p) as node_paths
MATCH (n1)-[:NEXT]->(m)-[:BRANCH]->(n2)
WITH collect(m) as branch_nodes , node_paths
RETURN branch_nodes,node_paths
```

Now `node_paths` consists of all the paths with pattern `(node)-[:NEXT]->(node)-[:NEXT]->...(node)` . Now you have the paths and branch Nodes(starting point of basically all the paths in the `node_paths` except the one which will be emerging from `root` node) , you can arrange the output order accordingly.

Comment: "which I dont think is not possible using only Cypher." : How might this be possible using Java in addition to Cypher, or perhaps using the Java Traversal API instead?

Comment: see you have the paths.. each path has collection of nodes.. the first node of every path will be a branch node which you will get from the other set of branch_nodes to match with... whereas the only path with root node not having any match in the branch_nodes will be the root of your tree..